# How to read content in a line of a file.txt

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a line like this:

`114765 * 3 * 659300 * 01 * 17/01/2013 *  * 1 * Chuck Norris * Chuck Norris Jr* Owner * 1 * 28/04/1983 * Conjuge *  *  * 16/1/2013 * 1 * Quadro Social *`

As you can see, the content/fields are separted by `*` they are fields like  `matriculation, name, dependent's name, category` etc... I'd like to know how could I ´read` it, one by one ?

Also I need to reorder this and write a new file.txt, with these content reordered and without the `*`... I'm totally lost !
After I read it and remove the `*` I need to replace them like `\field\`:
`\114765\\3\\659300\\01\\17/01/2013\\1\\Chuck Norris\`
I tried `substring()` and `StreamWriter` `StreamReader` `ReadLine` but I couldn't do what I need ;\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.Split` to get a `string[]` of the columns. You can use `String.Join` to join all parts together to a new string and `File.WriteAlltext` or `File.WriteAllLines`  to write it back.

> After I read it and remove the * I need to replace them like \field\:

So you need to replace the `*` with `\`:

```
string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string newLine = string.Join("", parts.Select(p => string.Format("\\{0}\\", p.Trim())));
File.WriteAllText(filePath, newLine);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/SnahEy)

Result:

```
\114765\\3\\659300\\01\\17/01/2013\\\\1\\Chuck Norris\\Chuck Norris Jr\\Owner\\1\\28/04/1983\\Conjuge\\\\\\16/1/2013\\1\\Quadro Social\\\
```

**Update**:

If you want to ignore parts that are empty(caused by two consecutive `* *` in the string), then you can use this code:

```
var nonEmptyParts = parts
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .Select(p => string.Format("\\{0}\\", p.Trim()));
string newLine = string.Join("", nonEmptyParts);
```

That'll result in:

```
\114765\\3\\659300\\01\\17/01/2013\\1\\Chuck Norris\\Chuck Norris Jr\\Owner\\1\\28/04/1983\\Conjuge\\16/1/2013\\1\\Quadro Social\
```

> I'd want to ignore the first 2 strings of the array, you know just
>   remove it, throw it away

That is `Enumerable.Skip`:

```
var nonEmptyParts = parts.Skip(2)
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .Select(p => string.Format("\\{0}\\", p.Trim()));
```

Comment: After I read it and remove the `*` I need to replace them like:
`\114765\\3\\659300\\01\\17/01/2013\\1\\Chuck Norris\` any tip ?

Comment: @Ghaleon: Edited my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Actually, I need to remove the `*` and separete the strings again but now with `\` but also insert `\` in the begining of the string. `\field\`

Comment: @Ghaleon: What is the desired result?

Comment: Read a TextFile with a lot of lines like that one. Get this,
`114765 * 3 * 659300 * 01 * 17/01/2013 * * 1 * Chuck Norris * Chuck Norris Jr* Owner * 1 * 28/04/1983 * Conjuge * * * 16/1/2013 * 1 * Quadro Social *`

and leave like this:
`\114765\3\\659300\\01\\17/01/2013\\ \\1\\Chuck Norris\\Chuck Norris Jr\\ Owner\\1\\28/04/1983\\Conjuge\\16/1/2013\\1\\Quadro Social\`

Comment: @Ghaleon: What is the difference between yours and mine? Why do you have double-backslahes e.g. before "Chuck Norris"? There is just one `*` before, so i don't know why you need two `\\`.

Comment: Look, i'm doing it this way with "\field\" so `\field1\\field2\\field3` because it is the way CorelDraw Understands what fields it has to impress, you know ? I know it's boring but should be this way, with `\field` +1 field then other `\field\` that's way it gets two `\\` got it? Is it possible ?

Comment: @Ghaleon: Edited my answer again. Have a look, i think i've got it now.

Comment: Oh yeah ! That's it *-* Just one more little think, how do I ignore the empty field ? e.g `114765 * 3 * * Chuck Norris * 1 * 5` There is two ` * * ` because one field is empty, how could I ignore it ? then I would not have three `\\\` ? It's the last thing missing then we are done. Really Thank you for helping me out @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Ghaleon: I though the `*` is a placeholder for a column separator, then it would make no sense to remove the white-space or the additional \\. I've already used `RemoveEmptyEntries` and `String.Trim` to remove any white-spaces, but i thought that the placeholder itself should not be removed. Do you want to exclude parts that are empty? I'll edit my answer.

Comment: yeah, I thought I would need this empty space to replace for '0' but I will not need it. I'd like to exclude the empty space so i'll have only `\` and `\\` and no `\\\` =) Really Thank you Tim !

Comment: @Ghaleon: Edited my answer to remove the empty parts.

Comment: Maan you are so good omfg u.u hope some day i'll get the level you are hehe... Worked just perfect ! Now one last litle thing, If I'd want to ignore the first 2 strings of the array, you know just remove it, throw it away... Would that be possible ? Because I think i'll not have to pass all of these fields to coreldraw ;s You're awesome !! Thanks !

Comment: @Ghaleon: Edited again, use `Skip(2)`. If you want to skip the first two non-empty parts, add `Skip(2)` after the `Where`.

Comment: Perfect... You Rock ! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

readline is what you need to read one line from the text file. once you have that whole line in a string, you use the Split method.

```
line.Split('*');
```

Will give you an array of strings.

Comment: Since `Split` takes a `char` as parameter (not a string), you can't add spaces.

Comment: Actually there is an overload that takes an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Read you file in a line at a time and then use

```
myLine.split('*');
```

This will separate the string into an array, splitting it where ever there is a '*'. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx for further details.

When you want to write it back out to another file you should just be able to arrange the items in the array as you want and write them using a StreamWriter, making sure you pass in your new file name. See http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter for an example.

Comment: OK, but the `dependen's id` sometimes comes empty so it's like `* *´ see the `empty space` ? How Could I get this empty space too ? Then I could create a function to replace(" ",0); get it ?

Comment: I think string.split should still give you the empty spaces in this situation.

Comment: Yes, even if you had a string "***", you would have an array of 3 with empty strings if I remember right, that's why you can add a parameter to Split telling it to remove empty results.

Comment: How create a `NEW` file.txt instead add lines on my first.txt file or overwrite it... ?

Comment: added explanation. Just pass in your new file name to the streamwriter.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for reordering the lines in the file? Just change the value of fieldToSortBy to order by other numeric fields.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FileSorter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fieldToSortBy = 0;

            //data.txt contains lines like 114765 * 3 * 659300 * 01 * 17/01/2013 * * 1 * Chuck Norris * Chuck Norris Jr* Owner * 1 * 28/04/1983 * Conjuge * * * 16/1/2013 * 1 * Quadro Social *
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\data.txt");
            var splitLines = lines.Select(l => l.Split('*'));
            var orderedLines = splitLines.OrderByDescending(l => int.Parse(l[fieldToSortBy].Trim()));
            var joinedLines = orderedLines.Select(l => string.Join("*", l));
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\output.txt", joinedLines);
        }
    }
}
```